# How to initialise View Controller in a Project with Two Storyboards iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an App, which has `main.storyboard` I am able to initialise the required view controller on App load by selecting `isInitialViewController` as shown below.

[image]

I have now added another storyboard to my project, called `Customer.Storyboard`.

I have two questions.

1. Where exactly in the code are we telling that the `main.storyboard` has to be loaded first ?
2. How can I initialise a view from `Customer.storyboard` on App load (  by selecting `is initial View Controller` in `Customer.Storyboard` doesn't work, it loads a view from `main.storyboard`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your Info.plist
2. delete the main.storyboard loading from your plist and alter your didfinishwithlaunchingoptions func:

   ```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 

   [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "XXX", bundle: nil)

   let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignupVC")

   self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
   self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   return true
   ```

   }

On the Plist u set the starting Storyboard to use. By default, it is main.
**Note: XXX is used to represent the name of whichever new file you would like to use.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a great step by step tutorial about this with best practices.](https://medium.com/@gurdeep060289/clean-code-for-multiple-storyboards-c64eb679dbf6)

A clean way to get a Storyboard intense. Later on the tutorial you will find a clean way to get the ViewController instance.

```
enum AppStoryboard: String {
   case main = "Main"
   case preLogin = "PreLogin"
   case timeline = "Timeline"
   var instance : UIStoryboard {
       return UIStoryboard(name: rawValue, bundle: Bundle.main)
   }
}

// USAGE :

let storyboard = AppStoryboard.Main.instance
```

About your question: On the project Plist u set the first Storyboard. By default it's the main.

Answer (score 1):

You should know two concepts: "default interface for app" and "default scene(view controller) for storyboard".

"default interface for app" is set on Info.plist, see the image below
[default interface for app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmaMy.png)

"default scene(view controller) for storyboard" is set by `isInitialViewController`

So if you want to launch `MainViewController` in Main.storyboard, you should set default interface as Main.storyboard

If you want to initial `CustomViewController` in Custom.storyboard, you can set `isInitialViewController` in `CustomViewController` as true.

Then you can get `CustomViewController` instance by `UIStoryboard(name: "Custom", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateInitialViewController()`

And if you want to initial a ViewController which is not an initialViewController, you can get instance by `UIStoryboard(name: "Custom", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewController")`. Before this you should set `Storyboard ID` in your storyboard.
[Storyboard ID in storyboard file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLqhd.png)